# Add support for OpenSSL in PHP without recompiling

Tags: php, openssl, recompile

Is this possible?  I'm on Mac OSX.

I'm using a custom install already, with the Mac OSX default**ish** apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by:

cd {php_dir}/ext/openssl

phpize
./configure
make && make install

Restart apache