# Openssl not found in phpinfo()

Tags: php, macos, openssl, php-extension

I am unable to detect Openssl support in php (MacOSx - Mountain Lion). Using phpinfo() function, i get the following - **OpenSSL support    disabled (install ext/openssl)**

i have made changes in php.ini file, to load the extension as well.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_include = On
```

i can also detect the openssl version in the terminal,

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

Why is php unable to detect Openssl ?

Comment: Have you tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544805/add-support-for-openssl-in-php-without-recompiling)

Comment: I think this should work in my case, but i'm having some problem with phpize command. It says 'cannot find config.m4' ! What could be causing this. Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Searched a lot but could not find anything helpful, heres the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834363/phpize-cannot-find-config-m4)