# Error on installing Mediawiki 1.38 for personal use in MacOS. Error message : Installing some PHP extensions is required. Please install: intl

Tags: php, macos, xampp, homebrew, mediawiki

I'm using MacOS Big Sur 11.4 and XAMPP 7.4.29. I have only basic knowledge on php and html. I want to go through mediawiki installion on my Mac for personal use. I encounter error message like screenshot below which basically I need to install intl extention in my PHP

[image]

I followed the instruction given [here](https://medium.com/@agaetis/solved-install-intl-php-extension-for-xampp-and-magento-for-macos-mojave-41fa42336fc6)

1. `Brew install autoconf`
2. Change the path `PATH=”/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:${PATH}”`
3. Go inside the folder `cd ext/intl/`
4. Build `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize`
5. I encounter error message

> Cannot find config.m4. Make sure that you run '/Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

After that I found a stackoverflow pages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834363/phpize-reports-cannot-find-config-m4) addressing the issue of config.m4 and suggesting to

1. Install xdebug-2.6.1 (which was written 9 years ago and I can not find in internet)
2. Finding the file `ls config*` which I try and fail too

After that, I try to find other way to install the missing extention of php. I found [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp/32404183#32404183). I followed the instruction

1. `brew install icu4c`
2. `sudo pecl update-channels`
3. `sudo pecl install intl` . In this step I put the path of ICU `/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/`
4. I stucked with an error message like below

> /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found

> #include <unicode/ubrk.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.

> make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1

> ERROR: `make' failed

So that's all the thing that I have tried so far. My question since from the beginning has not been solved. How can I install the missing PHP extention so that I can proceed with the installation of mediawiki?

Thank you in advance